# auto create blog posts depending on list

Tags: plugins

I looked for a plugin, but couldn't find anything that suited me.
What I would like to see is: Say I have a list of zipcodes. I want a blog post for EACH zipcode that contains text (same for ALL the posts), except of course for that zipcode, which will be unique in each post, in body of post, and title.

is this possible?
(If not.. it would be a big pain to create thousands of blog posts with all the same content (basically)...)

Thanks

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic, but in general yes it is possible.

Comment: Haven't tried anything... I'm not sure if a plugin would do it, but it shouldn't be too hard to make I would think. (so far I'm not programming wp plugins or anything) But why make it if it's available?... If I can't get a plugin recommendation here, where can I get that?